# How to collect one part of shortcode as an array

Tags: php, wordpress, getelementsbyname

I have a short code in wordpress that looks like this

```
[wp_charts title="linechart" type="line" align="alignleft" margin="5px 20px" datasets="20,25,10,10,10,10,10,105,59,34,23,21,54,12,22,34,54,21,22,12,3,4,7,8,4,6,2,9" labels="25th,26th,27th,28th,29th,30th,31st,1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th,7th,8th,9th,10th,11th,12th,13th,14th,15th,16th,17th,18th,19th,20th,21st,22nd,23rd,24th" scaleoverride="true" scalesteps="8" scalestepwidth="10" scalestartvalue="0" scaleFontSize="16" canvaswidth="920px" canvasheight="460px" relativewidth="2" width="920px" height="460px" backgroundcolor="#000"]
```

and i need to collect the "datasets" as an array then add them and echo the total number but im not sure how. I know how to get an element by id but not how to get just that part of the short code.. any help would be appreciated

As a side note im using phpexec in word press to run php from within a post so if there is a method using php it would be best.

Update 
the $array is the thing that i need to populate with datasets

```
    <p style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="font-size: 14pt;">MILES WALKED BY DAY<br>
        TOTAL MILES SO FAR
        <?php

        $array = array(**this is the area i need to populate with datasets**); 
        $mystr = array_sum($array); 
        echo $mystr; 
        ?>
        </span>
        </strong>
        </p>
        [wp_charts title="linechart" id="chart" type="line" align="alignleft" margin="5px 20px" 
datasets="20,25,10,10,10,10,10,22,59,34,23,21,54,12,22,34,54,21,22,12,3,4,7,8,4,6,2,9" 
    labels="25th,26th,27th,28th,29th,30th,31st,1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th,7th,8th,9th,10th,11th,
    12th,13th,14th,15th,16th,17th,18th,19th,20th,21st,22nd,23rd,24th" sumdatasets='' 
    scaleoverride="true" scalesteps="10" scalestepwidth="5" scalestartvalue="0" 
    scaleFontSize="16" canvaswidth="920px" canvasheight="460px" relativewidth="2" 
    width="920px" height="460px" backgroundcolor="#000"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're registering that shortcode yourself, but in that case:

```
add_shortcode('wp_charts', 'wp_charts_shortcode');

function wp_charts_shortcode($atts) {
    if(isset($atts['datasets'])) {
        return array_sum(explode(',', $atts['datasets']));
    }
}
```

Comment: then I guess you'll have to go into the source of the plugin

Comment: I have no idea where and what to do in there.